# Error con react-flip-card-2

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs

La verdad no se porque falla ni cual es el **error** eh buscado diversas maneras de solucionarlo pero no todavía no lo logre, instale el modulo **react-flipcard-2** lo implemente, las cartas giran pero después de haber girado 2 cartas se rompe y me marca ese **error**, Que puedo hacer?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisa bien la documentación de flipcard, puede que falten parámetros y por eso no funciona correctamente

Comment: si, me marca error adentro del modulo de flip card, pero no sabría como reponerlo

Answer (score 1):

Lo que yo hice fue utilizar la libreria https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-card-flip.

1. npm i react-card-flip
2. Modificar el archivo Carta.js

Carta.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './Carta.css'
import ReactCardFlip from "react-card-flip";

export default class Carta extends Component {  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="carta" onClick={this.props.seleccionarCarta}>
        <ReactCardFlip
          isFlipped={this.props.estaSiendoComparada || this.props.fueAdivinada}
        >
          <div className="portada" key="front"></div>
          <div className="contenido" key="back">
            <i className={`fa ${this.props.icono} fa-5x`}></i>
          </div>
        </ReactCardFlip>
      </div>
    )
  }  
};
```